# svelte css not scoping, child component inheriting parent's css

Tags: html, css, svelte

So I thought that Svelte scopes the css as long as the style. But it seems that in practice, it still uses the plaintext class name, rather than a hashed kind of class name. This results in the child elements inheriting the parent's styling.

i.e. did not expect to see the class "title" in the element

[image]

Basically the layout

Parent.svelte

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="title">Parent</div>
    <Child/>
</div>

<style>
    .test {
        & .title {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Child.svelte

```
<div>
    <div class="title">
        Child
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .title {
        font-size: 3em;
    }
</style>
```

See the "About" page in the following link at the bottom.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/serene-sun-4r38z7?file=/src/routes/about/+page.svelte:1,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native CSS nesting is just [not supported yet](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8587).

Meanwhile you could use a pre-processor like SASS for nesting, e.g. via [`svelte-preprocess`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess).

> did not expect to see the class "title" in the element

That is also just a wrong assumption. It scopes the CSS rules by adding classes to selectors and elements, it does not *remove* classes from the DOM.